# Are only standard footprints ever used? What if a manufacturer wants a devices footprint but the manufacturer doesn't list it?

Tags: pcb, footprint

They want a BOM like this but the part I want doesn't list a footprint. It lists the components dimensions and then you have to make the footprint yourself so I don't think there is a standard name. What do I put here?

[image]

[Here's the part I need a footprint for.](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Cornell-Dubilier-CDE/AFK336M10B12T-F?qs=sGAEpiMZZMtZ1n0r9vR22T8%252BuHNIqGYSDcyyfzgHttE%3D)

[image]

Comment: I'd find a different manufacturer, I've never been asked for that in a bom.

Comment: You put whatever footprint is in your library.

Comment: The capacitor datasheet gives you a drawing of the package, and a drawing of the recommended land dimensions. What more do you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're overthinking this. It's the unique footprint name that shows up in your library.

But you can confirm with LCSC.

Comment: Though short your answer is what actually helped me figure out my problem. I was overthinking it. It just needed what I named each component in the schematic and the name of the package/footprint for that component (which I had made in Eagle). Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

SMD caps like that have standardized sizes and foot prints.

The name of that type of that package is apparently "V-chip". They are designated using the diameter and height of the can.

From Nichicon:
[image]

From Panasonic:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If after searching everywhere, you can't find the footprint name, invent your own, short but descriptive name.
Sometimes I write n/a. ;)